# Websocket bundle / Ratchet in symfony 3

Tags: php, sockets, symfony, websocket

How Can I save/handle form data when user will do next steps:

```
-> Fill form
-> Submit Form
-> Join to websocket channel.
-> Now I need to save formdata for current user in moment when He is joined to room.
```

I want use this data to pair two users for one chat room so this data should be visible for every user requests.

I'm totally don't know what object I should to use to do that :(

Do someone know how to do this? I'm using Gos WebsocketBundle for symfony.

Answer (score 0):

I I came up with way to do that.
I'm sure It is not right way but works.

I made global array for every connections

```
private $globals = array();
```

And now I'm doing something like this:

```
public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $connection, Topic $topic, WampRequest $request, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible)
{
        $user = $this->clientManipulator->getClient($connection);

        /* Saving current session to global array 
         * $event returns form data sent in json format
        */
        if ($topic->getId() === 'chat/global/waiting-room'){
            $this->globals[$connection->WAMP->sessionId] = $event;
            $this->globals[$connection->WAMP->sessionId]['id'] = $connection->WAMP->sessionId;
        }
}
```

Now I'm used perodic timer like this:

```
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $connection, Topic $topic, WampRequest $request)
{    
        ## global data:
        $topicTimer = $connection->PeriodicTimer;
        $allMembers = $this->clientManipulator->getAll($topic, true);
        $user = $this->clientManipulator->getClient($connection);
        $userSessionId = $connection->WAMP->sessionId;

        if ($topic->getId() === 'chat/global/waiting-room'){
           $userData = $this->globals[$connection->WAMP->sessionId];

            ## Set timer every 5 seconds
            if(!$this->periodicTimer->isPeriodicTimerActive($this, 'getPair-'.$userSessionId)){
                $this->periodicTimer->addPeriodicTimer($this, 'getPair-'.$userSessionId, 5, function() use ($userData, $userSessionId, $topic) {

                ## my own method for pair searching in $this->globals; 
                $pair = $this->findPairForCurrentUser($userSessionId); 
                if(NULL !== $pair)
                {
                    #Send info to Two people about room and do redirect in jquery.
                    $topic->broadcast(
                            array(
                                'msg' => 'We did it! Connecting now...', 
                                'room' => array(
                                    'slug' => uniqid("room"),
                                    'id'   => rand(0,1923)
                                )
                            ), 
                            array(), 
                            array(
                                $userData['id'],
                                $pair
                            )
                    );

                    # Remove perodic timer :)
                    $this->periodicTimer->cancelPeriodicTimer($this, 'getPair-'.$userSessionId);
                }
            });
            }
}
```

- CONCLUSIONS:

  - Main id for detect people is current websocket session id.
  - global array where KEY is current ws session id is handling form data
  - Every connection starts new perodic timer called "getPair-" + current ws session id
  - At disconnect I'm checking that global array with current ws session id is set. If yes, destroy.